# Issue with assigning an Int Value to textfield

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I have an `Int` variable defined like so...

```
var otpNo = Int()
```

Now, an `integer` value has been assigned to this variable.

Now I have passed this int value to another `viewcontroller` and in that viewcontroller, I want to assign this int value to a textfield. But I am not able to do so.

I have tried this...

```
Int(myTextField.text!) = otpNo
```

But I am getting this `error` message:

> Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value

Comment: this is not the good way to declare the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the value like so:

```
myTextField.text = "\(otpNo)"
```

A [UITextField's text property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text) accepts `String` type. You will need to convert your `Int` into a `String`, instead of what you were trying in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

You can assign text as follow :

`myTextField.text = String(format: "%d", otpNo)`

`myTextField.text = "\(otpNo)"`

Comment: Ideally, since it's something presented to the user, `NumberFormatter` should be used.

Answer (score -1):

When you wrap a string in Int(), you're creating an immutable representation of that string, as an Int. You can't assign anything to that representation - it's just a number

`myTextField.text = String(describing: optNo)`

This converts the int to a string, and assigns it to the text property of that text field.